Wearing a Bendel Minhag Chabad
Minhag Chabad is to wear a Gartel (generally called a Bendel) all the time under the shirt. This accomplishes 2 things:

Separates the heart and Erva for davening etc.

Keeps the Tzitzis in place so that they are an Amoh wide the entire time.


After marriage, the Minhag is to continue wearing the Bendel but to wear a Gartel over the jacket when davening or performing various Mitzvos.
If one continues to wear the Bendel, why does one need a Gartel?
(I'm not asking why if one has a Gartel then by marriage why do they continue wearing a bendel, because it continues to hold the Tzitzis in place so that would make sense)
I have heard a nice explanation that just like a Sefer Torah if its kosher then belt is on the inside but if it's passul then the belt goes on the outside. So a bachur who is involved in Torah etc. is "kosher" but a married man has a home a wife and kids and therefore is less involved he is "passul".
But this is a nice thought, not a halchic reason.

2 thoughts. In the days before elastics the bochurim would wear gartels as a bendel. There is a story with the rebbe to that effect. Also, the reason we wear a gartel when praying is because of “Hachon…”, which is preparing oneself for prayer.
